# Countdown timer with session in php

Tags: php

I want to make a countdown timer, for online quiz that has divided into many portion like MCQS fill in the blank question..the countdown times that can be used on several places in many pages..

Comment: Hi Muhammed, first of all: welcome. Please provide what you already tried to solve this. You could also provide more specific examples of what you want to achieve. You will also need to be mor specific why you want a session for this (do you really need to?)

Comment: i tried to find countdown timer for many pages from last 3 day but i can't .. and i'm working on final year project that's about online quiz and has many portion like MCQS, fill in the blank, and question and i want display this countdown timer through session in different pages ...if it works with out session in different pages then i do not need session ...

Comment: sir i want to redirect page automatically when the countdown timer complete...

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here - as said there is no real need to use a session even though it can be better.

Basically you could to a countdown timer using javascript and use

```
window.open('url');
```

To redirect as soon as the timer goes to 0 ( http://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/ )

This will work, however you will have the problem that anyone could enter you code via inspection and change stuff in you js to skip the timer / redirect.

Therefore you could use a session to achieve what you want

1. Create new date and store it in session when person starts

   ```
     $date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
     $_SESSION['date'] = strtotime($date) * 1000; // store in ms
   ```
2. You would then need to perform requests against your backend to get the remaining time

   ```
     $difference = strtotime(date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')) - $_SESSION['date']; // Return diff in ms
   ```

With this you will still need to provide a JS implementation. The php / session part is only about validation of what the user experiences